# DateTimePicker.value will not accept date string I'm passing to it - vb.net

Tags: mysql, string, vb.net, date, datetimepicker

On one of my forms, I'm listing a load of services and corresponding dates.
Theres basically a list of services, a checkbox next to each one and a datetimepicker next to the checkbox. If the checkbox is checked, the datetimepicker is visible and the date is set to the contracted end date for that service, if not it is hidden (visible=false).

I read the data for this form in from mysql and stick it in a DataTable like this...

```
        Dim adapter As MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim productresultstable As DataTable
        cn.ConnectionString = main.myconnectionstr
        Dim commandtext As String
        commandtext = "Select * from products where link_id = '" & customerid & "'"
        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(commandtext, cn)
        productresultstable = New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(productresultstable)
```

Then I  sort through it accordingly, checking the relevant checkboxes and setting the datetimepickers.

```
        p1.Checked = productresultstable.Rows(0)("p1").ToString()
        If p1.Checked = True Then
            p1date.Visible = True
            p1date.Value = Date.Parse(productresultstable.Rows(0)("1_ce").ToString)
        End If
```

The correct checkboxes are all being checked; thats working fine.
But the datetimepickers all have the date as todays date.

I know that **productresultstable.Rows(0)("1_ce").ToString** is pulling in a date (1_ce is a column with type 'Date' in mysql) because if I add a messagebox so show it to screen, it shows "19/04/2018 00:00:00"...

[image]

but no matter what I try, I cant seem to get the value of the corresponding DateTimePicker to show this value.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? 
Any help is appriciated!

Comment: Why would you be passing it a date string at all?  The `Value` property is type `DateTime`, not type `String`.  Assign a `DateTime` value to it, not a `String` object.

Comment: Well thats why I'm using date.parse.... but I have also tried directly giving it the value without '.tostring' on the end without date.parse and with date.parse and tried cdate() also... none of which made any difference.

Comment: Have you actually debugged the code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through the code? Is that line hit, does that line succeed?  If you answered "yes" to both questions then the code is working as it should.  In that case, the issue is elsewhere, so we can't help based on the information you have provided.

Comment: I have and no errors are thrown. I've found the problem however - when you pointed this out, I did some more testing and if i use a new datetimepicker, it works fine.   at the start of my function there is a p1date.value = "" ... that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Further up my code there was ...

> p1date.value = ""

... which was causing the issue.

yes, I'm an idiot.